Ubuntu Cloud image not deploying in openstack
I am unable to deploy Ubuntu Cloud images(qcow2) in openstack and getting the following error message. My Openstack is working fine as I was able to successfully deploy the cirros image.

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 1654, in schedule_and_build_instances host_lists = self._schedule_instances(context, request_specs[0], File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 942, in _schedule_instances host_lists = self.query_client.select_destinations( File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/nova/scheduler/client/query.py", line 41, in select_destinations return self.scheduler_rpcapi.select_destinations(context, spec_obj, File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/nova/scheduler/rpcapi.py", line 160, in select_destinations return cctxt.call(ctxt, 'select_destinations', **msg_args) File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 190, in call result = self.transport._send( File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 123, in _send return self._driver.send(target, ctxt, message, File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 782, in send return self._send(target, ctxt, message, wait_for_reply, timeout, File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 774, in _send raise result nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 244, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/nova/scheduler/manager.py", line 243, in select_destinations raise exception.NoValidHost(reason="") nova.exception.NoValidHost: **No valid host was found.**

 openstack hypervisor list
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
| ID                                   | Hypervisor Hostname | Hypervisor Type | Host IP      | State |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
| 5740812e-472d-47f9-a75d-2f39a19915a9 | openstack           | QEMU            | 10.10.10.x | up    |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+

openstack compute service list
+--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Binary         | Host      | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| 0f5a2138-a6b5-42d8-9f40-823e1c7ff7bc | nova-scheduler | openstack | internal | enabled | up    | 2024-09-09T19:20:24.000000 |
| 015d27d3-0d3b-401a-94e5-067022412322 | nova-conductor | openstack | internal | enabled | up    | 2024-09-09T19:20:24.000000 |
| 45ad3d14-8520-4ecd-af8b-38b9d457590d | nova-compute   | openstack | nova     | enabled | up    | 2024-09-09T19:20:25.000000 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+

This is where I have downloaded the image file
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/bionic/release-20230602/
Any help will be appreciated.

If you're getting a "no valid host was found" error, you need to inspect your nova compute scheduler logs; there should be information there showing why your hosts are being rejected.
